Canonical phase for "mixing" of irreps with multiplicities
Take for example the irreps $8,8'$ of $A_2$. For any two irreps with multiplicity you can "mix" them: $(R_1',R_2')=(R_1,R_2).((c,s),(-s,c))$ where the latter is a rotation matrix ($s=\sin(\phi),c=\cos(\phi)$). If $R_1,R_2$ are Schur-orthogonal, so are $R_1',R_2'$. But what is the favorite choice of $\phi$? For $8,8'$ obviously you want $8$ to be the adjoint, which fixes $\phi$. (Does it?) But what if $R_1,R_2$ are two generic irreps? For example, you could look at the R symbols (if you consider the quantum version of the Lie algebras). Assume $(R_1,R_1,R_1)$ is a legit triad ($R_1\otimes R_1$ contains $R_1$). Then you could choose $\phi$ to make the R symbols of $R_1$ and $R_2$ of this triad equal. (At least this would be my natural choice!) Or one R symbol being zero (whoops?).
So again, what is the preferred choice (if existing) to fix such a phase?
EDIT: This all is of course only meaningful for irrep pairs $R_1,R_2$ where "$(R_1,R_3,R_4)$ is a legit triad" always implies "$(R_2,R_3,R_4)$ is a legit triad". (Is that the difference between outer and inner multiplicities?)
